# How do you change a Meteor app to use the OAuth redirect flow?

Tags: android, meteor, ios8, oauth-2.0, meteor-accounts

I just added `accounts-google` to my Meteor app, and answered that I wanted the default OAuth flow, `popup`. I don't know why this is the 'default', it is broken on iOS8, and inside WebViews, and many other places (see discussion [->here](https://meteor.hackpad.com/OAuth-redirect-flow-o9muBCn14pE)).

Anyway, I have `houston`, and dont see any relevant collections, and I'm not sure where the config gets stored, or how to change it. Many thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Aha, first do `meteor add service-configuration` to get the relevant smart package, then you can include this code at will

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
  {service: 'google'},
  {$set: {loginStyle: 'redirect'}}
)
```